# Replace multiple values in a matrix

Tags: r, replace

`a` is a matrix:

```
a <- matrix(1:9,3)

> a
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    7
[2,]    2    5    8
[3,]    3    6    9
```

I want to replace all the 1 to good, all the 4 to medium, and all the 9 to bad.

I use the following code:

```
a[a==1] <- "good"
a[a==4] <- "medium"
a[a==9] <- "bad"

> a
     [,1]   [,2]     [,3] 
[1,] "good" "medium" "7"  
[2,] "2"    "5"      "8"  
[3,] "3"    "6"      "bad"
```

It works, but is this the simplest way to work it out? Can I combine these codes into one command?

Comment: Nested `ifelse`s, but I'm not sure that's better. Also dubiously better: `a[] <- dplyr::recode(a, \`1\` = 'good', \`4\` = 'medium', \`9\` = 'bad', .default = as.character(a))`

Comment: If you really are applying categorical or ordinal labels, you should probably use a data.frame with factor variables. As far as I can tell (by trying out @zx8754 's answer), factor variables don't play nice with matrices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `cut()`:

```
matrix(cut(a, breaks = c(0:9),
           labels = c("good", 2:3, "medium", 5:8, "bad")), 3)
```

But not really happy with manual labels bit.

Maybe using `match()`, more flexible:

```
res <- matrix(c("good", "medium", "bad")[match(a, c(1, 4, 9))], 3)
res <- ifelse(is.na(res), a, res)
```

Comment: Another option would be `findInterval`.

Comment: @akrun Do you mind adding as an answer or edit existing one?

Comment: You can add it to yours.  It is just a similar solution as `cut`

Answer (score 2):

`car::recode()` does nicely here, returning the same matrix structure as was given as input.

```
car::recode(a, "1='good';4='medium';9='bad'")
#      [,1]   [,2]     [,3] 
# [1,] "good" "medium" "7"  
# [2,] "2"    "5"      "8"  
# [3,] "3"    "6"      "bad"
```